# Part of speech: "get to sleep" and "get to work"

Tags: parts-of-speech

In phrases "get to sleep" and "get to work", are "sleep" and "work" used as nouns or verbs?

Examples:

> - It took me almost an hour to **get to sleep** last night.
> - Let's **get to work** now!

If they are nouns, is it possible to modify them with adjectives? Or if they are verbs, can they modified with adverbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Sleep" and "work" are both used as nouns here**. As nouns, common ways to modify them are "good sleep", "sound sleep", "hard work", "good work" (though in this expression, modifiers are not usually added). Of course, in their verb forms, adverbs can be added.